# PHP PDO MYSQL -> Query using PDO Class - Selecting Different Tables with same name fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, pdo

I have two tables im mysql, for example on table is called **worker** and the other one is called **interventions**.

The Table "**worker**" has 3 fields:

- ID
- Name
- Email

The table "**interventions**" has 3 Fields as well:

- ID
- NameId
- Description

I want to cross data between both tables.
**Here is the code of PDO Class:**

```
    class PdoInsideClass {
    public  $ID, $Name , $NameId, $Description ;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->ID = "{$this->ID}";
        $this->Name = "{$this->Name}";
        $this->NameId = "{$this->NameId}";
        $this->Description = "{$this->Description}";
    }
}
```

**The Database Query**

```
$myquery = $database_connection->query( 'SELECT * FROM 
                                        worker, interventions
                                        WHERE worker.ID=interventions.NameId
                                        ');
$myquery->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'PdoInsideClass');
```

**Table and the Loop**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID of the Intervention</th>
        <th>Description Of the Job</th>
        <th>Id of the Worker</th>
        <th>Name of the Worker</th>
    </tr>   
    while ($result = $myquery->fetch()) {
        echo "<tr>"; //OPEN TABLE
        echo '<td>' . $result->ID . "</td>"; //ID of the Intervention
        echo '<td>' . $result->Description . "</td>"; //Description Of the Job
        echo '<td>' . $result->ID . "</td>"; //Id of the Worker
        echo '<td>' . $result->Name . "</td>"; //Name of the Worker
        echo "</tr>"; // CLOSE TABLE

    }
    ?>
</table>
```

**The problem:** When I print this i get two fields that are the same (ID of the Intervention AND Id of the Worker);

**The question is:** How can i select the ID of the table that I want ? By default the ID selected is the first table of the query -- `'SELECT * FROM worker, interventions'` -- in this case is the table worker.

**Solved awesers that I'm not looking for:**
Querying this -> `$this->NameId = "{$this->NameId}";` 
Insted of this -> `$this->ID = "{$this->ID}";`

**My goal is:** I  want to know if its possible to querying diferent tables with fields with same names, and specifing the order and not defined by what i put first in the query.

Comment: You need to use joins here.  Link the two tables with a foreign key

Comment: @Akin he is using joins just in a round about way rather than explicitly using the `INNER JOIN` keyword, he's doing it on the `WHERE` clause instead. That won't solve his problem either.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple ways of solving this.

> Change your database schema

Instead of using `id` as your primary key, perhaps name it `worker_id` and `intervention_id` as it's more explicit in it's meaning rather than being implicit in it's meaning.

That might not be feasible right now, but something to keep in mind for future for better database design.

> Change your query and alias columns

Rather than doing

```
SELECT * FROM 
worker, interventions
WHERE worker.ID=interventions.NameId
```

Explicitly define the columns and alias them as neccessary

```
SELECT
    worker.id as worker_id,
    interventions.id as intervention_id
WHERE
    worker.ID=interventions.NameId
```

This will be the perhaps the simplest as it requires no database schema changes or updating of all your queries, just the ones you need this.

> Access by array position rather than name

Since you have two or more columns with the same name, you are overwriting the value with the most recent one, in this case the id on interventions is overwriting the id on worker.

In order to do that you'll need to do that it will require several changes. I however would **not** recommend this as every time you add new columns or change the order of columns your code **WILL** break.

Comment: I think this is the best solution ---Change your query and alias columns--- . There is way to update the code Like: $result->TABLE_NAME->ID ? || I want to re use the code as much as possible.

Comment: Every time you alias the columns your class is going to need to know about those columns. Based on what you want to do, my first suggestion will solve the problem as you'll never have issues with overwriting values as in theory the columns will contain the same values.

Comment: there is a way to do something like this ? $result->interventions->ID

Comment: No you cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to specify which columns you want in which order:

```
SELECT worker.ID, worker.name, worker.email, 
  interventions.ID, interventions.nameid, interventions.description
FROM  worker, interventions
WHERE worker.ID=interventions.NameId
```

Put them in any order you want...

```
SELECT  worker.name, worker.email, interventions.description
  interventions.ID, interventions.nameid, worker.ID
FROM  worker, interventions
WHERE worker.ID=interventions.NameId
```

You can even give them a new name to make them easier to identify in the result set (this is called an Alias)

```
SELECT  worker.name, worker.email, interventions.description
  interventions.ID as InterventionsID, interventions.nameid, 
  worker.ID as WorkerID
FROM  worker, interventions
WHERE worker.ID=interventions.NameId
```